# Python i would like to know how to writerow with a for loop (DictWriter)

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write csv file with DictWriter .
So far i  have created a list and a loop but it only writes the last row of the list , number of times how many items are in the list.
This is my code:

```
fieldnames = ['Code', 'Hight', 'Country']
with open('write.csv', 'w',newline="") as f:
  w = csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames=fieldnames,delimiter = "\t")
  w.writeheader()
  for i in my_list:
    w.writerow({"Code":code,"Hight":hight,"Country":country})
```

Comment: What is `my_list` here?

Comment: its a list with data in it  : code , hight ,country
created like so :
my_list.append([code , hight , country])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing the same variable on each iteration of the for loop. If `my_list` is a list of dictionaries, the code should be:

```
for i in my_list:
    w.writerow({"Code": i['code'], "Hight": i['hight'], "Country": i['country']})
```

If `my_list` is a list of lists,

```
for i in my_list:
    w.writerow({"Code": i[0], "Hight": i[1], "Country": i[2]})
```

Comment: TypeError: list indices must be integersor slices, not str

Comment: @GWL That means my_list is a list of lists. So take the second example

Comment: Thanx for the help , interesting at first i tryid second one as well but i might have miss typed something

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

import csv

nms = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]

f = open('numbers2.csv', 'w')

with f:

```
writer = csv.writer(f)

for row in nms:
    writer.writerow(row)
```